# Count the words in a file that match the words in a String [ ]

Tags: java, arrays, string, file

I am writing a program to read a file and count the occurrences of specific words within that file.

I have got the code working to a point. I put the words I want to count in a String []. The problem is that the program either counts the occurences of all the words in the file (including the ones I do not want to count) or it counts the words in the String [].

How do I go about getting the program to count the words in the file that match the words in the array? I've looked through many similar questions and have tried using StringTokenizer and Lists but can't get them fully working either.

My aim is that if my file has the text " yellow red blue white black purple blue", I want my output to be "red: 1, blue: 2, yellow: 1"

I just want a nudge in the right direction, I know it is something silly I am stuck on, and as always, any constructive feedback is appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```
static String[] words = { "red", "blue", "yellow", "green" };

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    System.out.println("This program will count the occurences of the specific words from a text file.");

    System.out.println("\nThe words to be counted are; red, blue, yellow, and green.\n");

    Map map = new HashMap();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("colours.txt"))) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {

            words = line.split(" "); // keeping this counts all words separated by whitespace, removing it counts words in my array instead of the file, so I'll get red: 1, blue: 1, yellow: 1 etc.,

            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

                if (map.get(words[i]) == null) {

                    map.put(words[i], 1);
                }

                else {

                    int newValue = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(map.get(words[i])));

                    newValue++;

                    map.put(words[i], newValue);
                }

            }

            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());

            line = br.readLine();
        }
    }

    Map<String, String> sorted = new TreeMap<String, String>(map);

    for (Object key : sorted.keySet()) {

        System.out.println(key + ": " + map.get(key));
    }
}
```

Comment: `Files.lines(Paths.get("colours.txt"))
  .flatMap(Pattern.compile(" ")::splitAsStream)
  .filter(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(words))::contains)
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
  .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));`

Comment: @ochi Which is why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: @shmosel you should!!! it's pretty impressive (oh, and it does work!!! just tried it ;) )

Comment: @shmosel I can kind of understand how this works but I don't yet have the knowledge to implement that into my code. I will try to though :)

Comment: That is the whole code. Put in in your `main()` and you're set.

Comment: You can add the code from @shmosel right after the line that outputs 'The words to be counted are...' - and replace everything else below with his code...

Comment: @shmosel Very impressive, looks a lot neater and I think, makes more sense, even just at a glance. I have a long way to go!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue above is that your are overriding the initial array or `words` when you split the line that you just read.

I have written this (modified variable names a bit for my own understanding)

(**updated** based on comments, thanks @shmosel)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    String[] keywords = {"red", "blue", "yellow", "green"};
    // for easier querying contents of array
    List keywordList = Arrays.asList(keywords);

    System.out.println("This program will count the occurrences of the specific words from a text file.");
    System.out.println("\nThe words to be counted are: " + keywordList + ".\n");

    Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<>();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/file/colours.txt"))) {
        // read a line
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            // keeping this counts all words separated by whitespace, removing it counts words in my array instead
            // of the file, so I'll get red: 1, blue: 1, yellow: 1 etc.,
            String[] words = line.split(" ");

            for(String oneWord : words ){
                if( keywordList.contains(oneWord)){
                    // thanks @ shmosel for the improvement suggested in comments
                    wordMap.merge(oneWord, 1, Integer::sum);
                }
            }

            line = br.readLine();
        }
    }

    Map<String, Integer> sorted = new TreeMap<>(wordMap);

    for (Object key : sorted.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + ": " + wordMap.get(key));
    }
}
```

Comment: `wordMap.merge(oneWord, 1, Integer::sum);`

Comment: Yeah I see it now when it is pointed out to me, needed another array for the words in my file. Thanks for taking the time to show me how to implement the code, it is much appreciated. I'm going to try and figure out how and why it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

There are probably two issues in the code.

- Array 'words' is used initially to list the words you are interested.
  But you are using the same array to hold the words in the line.
  [see *words = line.split(" ");*] So use a different array to hold the words in the line.
- There is no check if the word (in initial list) exists in
  line. Need to add this check. Also, remember that a word can repeat many times in the same line.

Comment: Ah, such a rookie mistake :) Thanks for the feedback, I will try and incorporate a check once I get the code working.